# Spatial tree matching such that a sub tree of one tree should be matched to another tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, pattern-matching, networkx, bipartite

I have the following 2 trees.
Tree 1 with branches from br_a to br_i and a root point.
[image: Tree1]

Tree 2 with branches from br_a to br_c and a root point.

[image: Tree 2]

Each vertex/node in this tree has a position (x, y), and all edges have the same weight. I would like to perform a bipartite matching between the branches of Tree 1 and Tree 2, such that we obtain a sub tree of Tree 1 that best matches the Tree 2. So, if we match a Tree 1 branch to a Tree 2 branch then we must also match all the parent branches of the Tree 1 matched branch (up till the root point) to the parent branches of the Tree 2 matched branch. In the given example, the following sub tree of Tree 1 would be the best match because of the most similar topology and position of the nodes.

[image: sub tree]

How can I do this? Is there any tree matching algorithm for this kind of matching. One naive way of matching that I can think of is to create all possible sub tree permutations. For example,

[image]
[image]

Then match each of the sub tree to Tree 2, one by one, and pick the one with best match. Here my question is what algorithm can I use to match these trees that incorporates the position of the nodes as a matching criteria. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.